# Turn a numpy array of one hot row vectors into a column vector of indices

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

So what is a concise and efficient way to convert a numpy array like:

```
[[0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0]]
```

into a column like:

```
[[2],
 [0],
 [1]]
```

where the number in each column is the index value of the "1" in the original array of one hot vectors?

I was thinking of looping through the rows and creating a list of the index value of 1, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Just curious if the `np.argmax()` based solution worked too for your input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update*: For a faster solution, see Divakar's answer.

---

You can use the [`nonzero()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nonzero.html) of the numpy array.  The second element of the tuple that it returns is what you want.  For example,

```
In [56]: x
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])

In [57]: x.nonzero()[1]
Out[57]: array([2, 2, 3, 3, 0])
```

According to the [docstring of `numpy.nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), "the values in `a` are always tested and returned in row-major, C-style order", so as long as you have exactly one 1 in each row, `x.nonzero()[1]` will give the positions of the 1 in each row, starting from the first row. (And `x.nonzero()[0]` will be equal to `range(x.shape[0])`.)

To get the result as an array with shape (n, 1), you can use the `reshape()` method

```
In [59]: x.nonzero()[1].reshape(-1, 1)
Out[59]: 
array([[2],
       [2],
       [3],
       [3],
       [0]])
```

or you can index with `[:, np.newaxis]`:

```
In [60]: x.nonzero()[1][:, np.newaxis]
Out[60]: 
array([[2],
       [2],
       [3],
       [3],
       [0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

We are working with hot-encoded array that guarantees us exactly one `1` per row. So, if we just look for the first non-zero index per row, we would have the desired result. Thus, we could use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) along each row, like so -

```
a.argmax(axis=1)
```

If you wanted a `2D` array as o/p, simply add a singleton dimension at the end -

```
a.argmax(axis=1)[:,None]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [20]: # Let's create a sample hot encoded array
    ...: a = np.zeros((1000,1000),dtype=int)
    ...: idx = np.random.randint(0,1000,1000)
    ...: a[np.arange(1000),idx] = 1
    ...: 

In [21]: %timeit a.nonzero()[1] # @Warren Weckesser's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 9.03 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit a.argmax(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yup, `argmax(axis=1)` is better.